# ICheckbox toggle Checked/unChecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, icheck

UPDATE: the below code is firing the event but the only issue I'm having is: its not **unchecked** the checkbox, which is 
`$("input#crea").is(':checked') == false;`

I'm using ICheck plugin, what I'm trying to do is to: User should select only one checkbox and user can not check both....

```
 $('input').on('ifChecked', function (event) {
    if ($("input#rec").is(':checked')) {
        $("input#crea").is(':checked') == false;
    }
    else if ($("input#crea").is(':checked')) {
        $("input#rec").is(':checked') == false;
    }
});
```

Below is the rendered page looks like at the run time:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <input class="icheck" id="rec" name="rec" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="rec" type="hidden" value="false" /> <span style="color:black;">Receive</span>
</div>
<div class="form-group"> 
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"> </label>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
       <input class="icheck" id="crea" name="crea" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="crea" type="hidden" value="false" /> <span style="color:black;">Create</span>
       </div> 
 </div>
```

Comment: *"User should select only one checkbox and user can not check both"* -- Sounds like you'd be better off using radio buttons.

Answer (score 2):

You should uncheck checkbox like following.

```
$("input#crea").prop('checked', false);

$("input#rec").prop('checked', false);
```

Full event should look like below.

```
 $('input').on('ifChecked', function (event) {
    if ($("input#rec").is(':checked')) {
        $("input#crea").prop('checked', false);
    }
    else if ($("input#crea").is(':checked')) {
        $("input#rec").prop('checked', false);
    }
 });
```

Comment: Did not work and when I try to debug its not even debugging the first line

Comment: Sorry with your updated code does not work either; I'm debuggin through dev console and its not even firing the line, just you know that I'm using icheck plugin not the regular https://github.com/fronteed/icheck

Comment: `jquery` event should work even when you use a plugin. see my update for last time.